# Get full exececuted command from shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, arguments

I have a script that accepts a URL as one of it's arguments

so it could be evaluated like this

`script1 url -arg1 1`

but the URL may contain  `&`
, so it is interpreted like this

`script1 & brokenCommand -arg1 1`

I'd like to be able to read `brokenCommand -arg1 1` from `script1`

Is it possible? (without needing to input the url inside quotes)

Comment: @Cbhihe, the semicolon is not required: `&` is also a command terminator. See [3.2.3 Lists of Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) in the manual

Comment: @DyegoBr Do you mean `script2 -arg1 | script1` to send script2's output to script1's input? With the command as you show, script2's output is not connected to script1 in any way.

Comment: I asked in a more general way, but the issue is that `script1` arg is a URL and may contain `&` , thus the rest of the arg is evaluated as a new command and `script1` cant find the rest of the argument

Comment: I know that if the url is provided inside quotes, then this wouldnt be an issue. I'm just trying to provide a more user friendly experience

Comment: If you want something user friendly, you can ask for the URL from a `read` statement. You cannot issue a command with an unquoted `&` without the shell treating it as the backgrounding operator (or something otherwise special such as redirection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If your environment is `bash`, you must follow the bash rules. In bash, some characters have a special meaning, and if you want to avoid that you need to escape them, either with `\` or with quotes.

If you want something more user friendly, maybe you should choose another environment. Using `read` inside a bash script could be enough. However, when you start to complicate things, you realize that using quotes is not so much trouble.

Comment: Unfortunelly I can't use this solution.

I asked in a more general way, but the issue is that 
`script1` arg is a URL and may contain`&` , thus the rest of the arg is evaluated as a new command and `script1` cant find the rest of the argument

Comment: I know that if the url is provided inside quotes, then this wouldnt be an issue. I'm just trying to provide a more user friendly experience

Comment: I don't see why this gained a downvote... The fact is that `&` is a special operator in the POSIX shell, and so in Bash, so it _will_ need to be protected when used as a regular character. And there's nothing whatsoever the script gets to do about it, since it doesn't run yet when the command line is parsed...